# proof of an inequality $ \left( 1+ \frac{x}{p} \right) ^{p}$

Tags: inequality

Prove that for $x>0$ 
and
$0<p<q$:

$$\left( 1+ \frac{x}{p} \right) ^{p}  < \left( 1+ \frac{x}{q} \right)  ^{q} $$

Answer (score 7):

Hint:  Apply the Bernoulli inequality to

$$(1+x/q)^{q/p} > ...$$

Comment: Nice hint!  ... +1.

Comment: could you please explain more thoroughly how to use Bernoulli inequality to prove that? I was trying to prove this question but I couldn't find a way to use that as bound, since  $\frac{q}{p}>1$ and $0<\frac{q}{p}<1$ when using the Bernoulli inequality gives you an upper bound and a lower bound. I've been struggling with this question very much so help would be very appreciated.

Comment: @Jneven: $(1 + x/q)^{q/p} > 1 + (q/p)(x/q) = 1 + x/p$ Raising both sides to the power $p$ gives $(1 + x/q)^q > (1 + x/p)^p$.  The general inequality is if $a  >1$, then for any real number $\xi > 1$ we have $a^\xi > 1 + \xi(a-1)$ and for $0 < \xi < 1$ we have $a^\xi < 1 + \xi (a-1)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(1+\frac{x}{p}\right)^p = \left(1+\frac{x}{p}\right)^p\cdot 1^{q-p} \stackrel{\color{red}{AM-GM}}{\color{red}{\leq}}\left(\frac{p\cdot\left(1+\frac{x}{p}\right)+(q-p)\cdot 1}{q}\right)^q=\left(1+\frac{x}{q}\right)^q. $$